# Python pip raising NewConnectionError while installing django-braces

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error when I tried to install django-braces:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000168673EC2E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/6d/ce/accaea120b323e62cb3bf8cce26892cdbfbf6b86d1b220fa2432b9b86acb/django_braces-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

**I can install any other libraries without any problem.**

#### Questions:

- Is there any problem with `django-braces` ?
- If so, can you recommend an alternative to `braces.SelectRelatedMixin` ?

#### Versions:

- `python 3.9.2`
- `django 3.1.7`

Comment: Can you access https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6d/ce/accaea120b323e62cb3bf8cce26892cdbfbf6b86d1b220fa2432b9b86acb/django_braces-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Comment: I couldn't. What is in there ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4723#issuecomment-513512569

tl;dr

This message indicates that the DNS lookup likely failed. This can happen for a number of reasons, for example:

1. Trying to access PyPI from a corporate network that blocks access
2. Network connectivity issues

3. A configured index-url in one of your configuration files is pointing to a location that is not accessible. See here for a command that can help troubleshoot this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes companies have a private pip config of packages you can install. To bypass this you can unset the DNS pip is resolving to via
`pip3 config unset global.index-url`
command